# Abruptly kill a python thread which indirectly calls methods containing locks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

I have a thread (say thread_a) which execute a method (say method_a()). This method_a is calling method (say method_b) which uses a lock.I want to terminate this thread abruptly. How can I do this without damaging the consistency of the lock. Give bellow is a structure of my code,

```
def method_a()
    #codes
    method_b()
    #codes

def method_b()
    lock.acquire()
    #codes
    lock.release()

thread_a = threading.Thread(target=method_a)
thread_a.start()
```

What is the best way to terminate this thread_a. I want to keep the correct state of the lock even if the thread is killed abruptly. Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use the lock as a context manager: `with lock:`

Comment: OK. but how can I terminate the thread.  I am currently raising an exception on  the thread whenever I want to terminate the thread. But It is ruining the locks state.

Comment: With a context manager the lock should be released on an exception. Stopping a thread is generally not a trivial task, there are many things to consider, the best approach is in my opinion to make the thread function return.

Comment: Yeah.. My thread method returns values. And I think the exception releases a lock acquired in the thread method. But my lock is in the another method which is called by the thread method. So the lock is not properly released. Any idea?